# How to compile cpp project in github repository to exe?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, github, compilation, executable

I'm new to programming, so this might be a stupid question :)

So I found this project on github - https://github.com/GPUOpen-Effects/FidelityFX-CLI
and I want to "compile it to executable", but have 0 idea how to do that.
The project is done in VisualStudio

Can someone help me with that?
Thanks for reading :)

Comment: The fact that the project is hosted on GitHub has absolutely no bearing on how you compile it.

Comment: For that specific project you have to use [CMake](https://cmake.org/) to create files which can build the project. Then use those to do the actual build. Cmake can generate build-systems and projects for many tools and environments, for example it can be used to create Visual Studio projects.

Comment: That's why I'm asking. In the project description on Github, the author mentoins "the source code to build the executable". I wonder how to do that or what software to use

Comment: And is there a particular reason you want to compile it yourself, rather than using the prebuilt release?

Comment: Yes. Want to learn how people do that :)

Comment: Follow university courses about C++ programming, or at least take several weeks to read books about C++ programming (or pay someone who knows that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's got sub-modules which makes it tricky.

Start with this regardless of how you want to compile:

```
git clone https://github.com/GPUOpen-Effects/FidelityFX-CLI
cd FidelityFX-CLI
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Then (command line - assumes you've run the vcvars32.cmd or equivalent)

```
cl.exe /EHsc /MT FidelityFX_CLI.cpp d3d11.lib
```

**OR** - Just open a new VS project in the same FidelityFX-CLI folder.  You just need to FidelitFX_CLI.cpp and add d3d11.lib as a link library

**Best answer**

Just clone the repository in Visual Studio and let it build with CMake. This worked for me:

Start by doing a "Clone repository..." step
[image]

Just point it to the GitHub URL and press "Clone".

[image]

Let it do it's thing to clone everything (takes a few minutes).

[image]

Then build after the CMake file is generated.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate this!